# React Native Video source with headers

Tags: react-native, react-native-video

Does react-native-video support providing headers in the source like this:

```
<Video
   source={{
     uri: myUrl,
     method: 'GET',
     headers: {
       'some-header': 'some-value',
     }
   }}
   ...
/>
```

I need it for authentication purposes, it works fine to fetch a video with similar url without the headers, but for video that requires headers it does not load...

Side note: I know this is working properly for my `Image` components.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs it is possible:
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video#headers. Just pass it to the props like you normally would with an image source:

```js
source={{
  uri: "https://www.example.com/video.mp4",
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'bearer some-token-value',
    'X-Custom-Header': 'some value'
  }
}}
```